# How to decompose an ideal as intersection of simpler ideals?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> We have 
>   $$I=\left(x^2+2y^2-3,y(x-y),y(y+1)(y-1)\right)\subset\mathbb{C}[x,y]$$ 
>   and I would like to decompose it as intersection of simpler ideals. How could I proceed?

For example, in this case, could I write 
$$I=(x^2+2y^2−3,y,y(y+1)(y−1))∩(x^2+2y^2−3,x−y,y(y+1)(y−1))\ ?$$ Then could I make other similar simplifications? Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tool that may be helpful for this kind of stuff.

Proposition:  Let $I,J,K$ be ideals of a ring $R$ with $J + K = R$.  Then $$I + JK = (I + J)(I + K) = (I + J) \cap (I + K).$$

Proof:  $(I+J)(I+K) = I^2 + I(J+K) + JK = I + JK$.

Edit:  I probably should mention that the last equality is simply a special case of the fact that $IJ = I \cap J$ if $I + J = R$.  You can check this using the previously proven rule for products:
$IJ = ((I \cap J) + I)((I \cap J) + J) = (I \cap J) + IJ = I \cap J$.

Comment: In the question, you can write $I = A + (y)(y+1)(y-1)$, where $A = (x^2 + 2y^2 - 3, x(x-y))$ and $(y)$, $(y+1)$, and $(y-1)$ are pairwise comaximal, so you could split it up as $I = (A + (y))(A + (y+1))(A + (y-1))$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another hint.

After lots of work (at least for me), you find that you don't really need the last generator of the ideal, because
$$
\frac{y}{3}\left(x^2+2y^2-3\right) + \left(\frac{y+x}3 \right)(y^2-yx) = y^3-y=y(y-1)(y+1).
$$

Hence your ideal has two generators
$$
I = (x^2+2y^2-3,y^2-yx).
$$
The first factor is irreducible, but the second factor is not. Then geometrically, this correspond to the intersection of the circle (or ellipse?) given by $x^2+2y^2-3$ and the union of the lines $y=0$ and $y=x$. These intersection points are easily computed to be $(\pm \sqrt{3},0)$ and $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$. Hence your ideal should decompose as
$$
(y,x-\sqrt{3})\cap (y,x+\sqrt 3) \cap (x-1,y-1) \cap (x+1,y+1).
$$

This must be checked algebraically of course, since this kind of geometric reasoning is only valid up to radicals.

**NB:** It is a small lie that I found the relation above by myself. I asked Macaulay2 to give a set of minimal generators for the ideal. Then once I knew there was only two generators, it was not too hard to find the relation by experimentation.